# Checking if a date is between two other dates is not giving the right result

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating an app where I need to verify if a date is between two other dates.

Here you have an example from the dates that need to be verified:

```
[Evento(
  id: "1",
  inicioEvento: "2023-1-31 8:45",
  finEvento: "2023-1-31 9:45",
),
 Evento(
      id: "2",
      inicioEvento: "2023-2-1 08:45",
      finEvento: "2023-2-3 19:45",
  ),
  Evento(
      id: "3",
      inicioEvento: "2023-1-2 18:45",
      finEvento: "2023-2-2 19:45",
      asunto: "Prueba evento 3",
  )]
```

Here you have the function that is comparing the dates:

```
  bool isCurrentDateInRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
    final currentDate = DateTime.now();
    return currentDate.isAfter(startDate) && currentDate.isBefore(endDate);
  }
```

And here you the piece of code where I am checking if DateTime.now() is between the dates from Evento items.

```
 var isDateInRange = isCurrentDateInRange(dateTime1, dateTime2);

      print("esta dentro? ${asunto} ${isDateInRange}");
```

DateTime.now() should be between Evento['inicioEvento'] and Evento['finEvento'].

Printing out the result, it says that only Evento with id = 2 is true.

```
flutter: asunto es 0 Prueba evento 1
flutter: esta dentro? Prueba evento 1 false
flutter: asunto es 1 Prueba evento 2
flutter: esta dentro? Prueba evento 2 true
flutter: asunto es 2 Prueba evento 3
flutter: esta dentro? Prueba evento 3 false
```

But I think Evento with id = 3 should also be true.

```
DateTime.now() is 2023-2-2 11:37
```

Comment: I've tested with `currentDate = DateTime(2023, 2, 2, 11, 37);`, it is returning true

Comment: how are you parsing the dates?

Comment: In Flutter, you can use the DateTime class to parse a date string.

Example:

String dateString = '2020-04-20'; 
DateTime date = DateTime.parse(dateString); 
print(date); // 2020-04-20 00:00:00.000